# Poisson predictions and constant means

Tags: r, predict

I need to perform a Poisson regression analysis of how
number of visits to the doctor in the two week period varies as a function of age group, sex and illness. However, I need to hold sex and number
of illnesses constant at their mean values, and then predict rates of visits to a doctor over a two week period for different age groups.

Here is a sample of my data:

visits  gender  illness  age.category

```
   1 female       1          <30
   1 female       1          <30
   1   male       3          <30
   1   male       1          <30
   1   male       2          <30
   1 female       5          <30
   1 female       4          <30
   1 female       3          <30
   1 female       2          <30
   1   male       1          <30
```

However, I'm unsure of how to keep sex at its constant mean when making the prediction. Do I need to convert it into numeric first or do something else?

I know how to perform a poisson regression, it's making the prediction that I am struggling with.

Comment: there are (at least) two ways to do this; you could assume that the 'average' of sex is halfway (on the logit scale) between the male and female expectation, or that the average is weighted by the sex ratio in the population. This sounds like an exercise; do you have any idea what the person who set the exercise intended ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker No I do not know what they intended - that was all the information I was given. This is the example given for predicting rates of visits to a doctor over a two week period for men and for women (but keeping illness and age constant): 
sex <- factor(c('female', 'male',))
avg.age <- mean(DoctorVisits$age)
avg.illness <- mean(DoctorVisits$illness) .

hypothetical.person <- expand.grid(age=avg.age, gender=sex, illness=avg.illness) . 

 predict(M.dr, 
        newdata = hypothetical.person,
        type = 'response')

Comment: @BenBolker If you can make sense of what I have put, could you advise me on how I can apply this to my scenario?